# How to calculate $g^{ik}\nabla_k H$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $H$ be the mean curvature of a hypersurface $\Sigma \subset M$.

I know that

$$\frac{dH(t)}{dt} = \Delta_\Sigma\phi+ \text{Ric}(\nu,\nu)\phi + |A_{\Sigma}|^2\phi$$

but how about $g^{ik}\nabla_k H$; how to calculate it?

If I write

$$g^{ik}\nabla_k H = 0$$

since $H = const.$, is it true or not?

Thank you.

Comment: This should just be $\partial_iH$, right? Since $g(X,\nabla H) = dH(X)$ for any vector field $X$.

Comment: Yes if $H$ is a constant function then of course $\nabla_k H = 0$ for all $k$.

Comment: thank you........